# Protractor overriding selenium address?

Tags: selenium, protractor

Protractor is starting a selenium server itself when I tell it to use on on a different url? I have selenium server running on a Windows virtual machine and I am trying to run my tests through it:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'selemiumAddress': 'http://10.1.41.56:4444/wd/hub',
        'browserName': 'internet explorer'
    }
],
```

If I go to http://10.1.41.56:4444/wd/hub on my primary machine I can create a new internet explorer instance and it will have a internet explorer browser popup on the VM but when I run my protractor config file it just gives me a error:

> UnknownError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable; for more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki. The latest version can be downloaded from http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your capabilities:

```
'selemiumAddress': 'http://10.1.41.56:4444/wd/hub',
```

`selemiumAddress` should probably be `seleniumAddress`  (`N` vs `M`)

Comment: awesome :)  glad to hear it.  go ahead and mark this answer as accepted so this question can be closed @KevinM.Gilbert

Comment: Sorry was on lunch break :) @sircapsalot